# Get the latest status on same day

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking at call data: customer, status and date. (using Postgresql)
On some days the customer got different stati, how can I pick the latest status for that day?

Here is an excerpt:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (customer_id, date_called::date) cd.*
from calldata cd
order by customer_id, date_called::date, date_called desc;
```